# Align input fields in html without using CSS

Tags: html

I want to align input fields and I was asked to not use any css at all. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Travel Reservation Form</h1>

        <h3>* denotes mandatory </h3>

        <hr>

        <form>
            <input name="passengername" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="*Mobile Number" name="mobile" required>
            <br>
            <input name="mailid" placeholder="*Email ID" type="email" required>
            
            <select name="travelmonth">
                <option value="Month of Travel">Month of Travel</option>
                <option value="Aug2018">Aug2018</option>
                <option value="Sep2018">Sep2018</option>
                <option value="Oct2018">Oct2018</option>
                <option value="Nov2018">Nov2018</option>
                <option value="Dec2018">Dec2018</option>
                <option value="Jan2019">Jan2019</option>
                <option value="Feb2019">Feb2019</option>
                <option value="Mar2019">Mar2019</option>
                <option value="Apr2019">Apr2019</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <select name="package" required>
                <option value="*Origin">*Origin</option>
                <option value="GOA">GOA</option>
                <option value="MUMBAI">MUMBAI</option>
                <option value="KERALA">KERALA</option>
                <option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
                <option value="KOLKATA">KOLKATA</option>
            </select>
            

            <input name="destination" placeholder="Destination">
            <br>
            <input name=submit type="submit" value="Get A Call">
            <input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear">

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

The output this code is giving[image]

The output I'm required to get:[image]

How do I align the two input tags such that it looks the same as the posted image?

Comment: The requirement of not using CSS seems a bit arbitrary

Comment: You can use a table with border = 0, but the good practice is to use CSS.

Comment: I'm just getting started with html and I have no clue about css at all, and is it not possible to do it without css?

Comment: Cascading style sheets apply styles to a site, no styles without them!

Comment: @Pierre noooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: Spam &nbsp; because other than this I don't know how you can achieve it without css

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you actually can use styles to set the style of a page (because the content, a.k.a the HTML, is the same. And there is no behavior, a.k.a JavaScipt)

Example with bootstrap 5:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center text-uppercase">Travel Reservation Form</h1>
        <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">* denotes mandatory </h3>
        <hr>
        <form class="container">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-6">
              <input name="passengername" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <input type="tel" placeholder="*Mobile Number" name="mobile" required class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-6">
              <input name="mailid" placeholder="*Email ID" type="email" required class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <select name="travelmonth" class="form-select">
                <option value="Month of Travel">Month of Travel</option>
                <option value="Aug2018">Aug2018</option>
                <option value="Sep2018">Sep2018</option>
                <option value="Oct2018">Oct2018</option>
                <option value="Nov2018">Nov2018</option>
                <option value="Dec2018">Dec2018</option>
                <option value="Jan2019">Jan2019</option>
                <option value="Feb2019">Feb2019</option>
                <option value="Mar2019">Mar2019</option>
                <option value="Apr2019">Apr2019</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-6">
              <select name="package" required class="form-select">
                <option value="*Origin">*Origin</option>
                <option value="GOA">GOA</option>
                <option value="MUMBAI">MUMBAI</option>
                <option value="KERALA">KERALA</option>
                <option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
                <option value="KOLKATA">KOLKATA</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <input name="destination" placeholder="Destination" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-6">
              <input name=submit type="submit" value="Get A Call" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-secondary">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```